# The point inside a triangle where $a+f=c+e=b+d$ if $a, b$ and $c$ are side lengths and $d, e$ and $f$ are distances to the corners

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to find the general formula for finding the coordinate of a point within a triangle satisfying the condition $a+f = c+e = b+d$ where $a, b$ and $c$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle and $d, e$ and $f$ are the distances between the searched point and the corners of the triangle as shown in the figure.

The coordinates of the corners of the triangle are known and will be used for finding the coordinate of the point of interest.

I am sorry if this is a simple problem for which the answer is known and the searched point has a special name, but I could not find an online explanation.

Thanks.

[image]

The image shows an example triangle but the answer is searched for all types of triangles.

Comment: Artillery sound ranging.

Comment: This is center n. 176 (EQUAL DETOUR POINT) in the [Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This point it's an intersection of two hyperbolas:
$$e-f=a-c$$ with focuses $A$ and $C$ and
$$d-f=a-b$$ with focuses $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I guess that this point was not given a name previously, therefore I will call it "The Golden Point" of a triangle as it is the most important location in a triangle for me in my recently started research. From now on I will be trying to find (or write) a software which determines the coordinate of the golden point by using the coordinates of the corners of the triangle.

Comment: @Fatih Dikbas  OK. Equations of these hyperbolas we can get by given points $A$, $B$ and $C$.